# Trouble negotiating rsync protocol versions

Tags: linux, macos, mac, rsync

I am trying to rsync between a Linux box and a MacOS box.

The MacOS (yosemite) seems to come with an old version of rsync so I've updated that using homebrew.  OK, I seem to have perfectly matching versions:

```
wim@wim-imac:~$ rsync --version | head -n 1
rsync  version 3.1.1  protocol version 31
wim@wim-imac:~$ ssh wim@wim-dell
wim@wim-dell:~$ rsync --version | head -n 1
rsync  version 3.1.1  protocol version 31
```

If it's "pulling" from the MacOS box (i.e. the destination is local and the source is remote) it works:

```
wim@wim-imac:~$ rsync -nvvvv wim@wim-dell:/media/wim/wim_2tb/guitar /Volumes/wim2TB/guitar | grep Protocol
(Server) Protocol versions: remote=31, negotiated=31
(Client) Protocol versions: remote=31, negotiated=31
```

But if it's pushing from the source box (linux) to the mac, now there's a little problem - there's a protocol mismatch.

```
wim@wim-imac:~$ ssh wim@wim-dell
wim@wim-dell:~$ rsync -nvvvv /media/wim/wim_2tb/guitar wim@wim-imac:/Volumes/wim2TB/guitar | grep Protocol
(Server) Protocol versions: remote=31, negotiated=29
(Client) Protocol versions: remote=29, negotiated=29
```

So the symptom of this is since we've negotiates the lowest common denominator protocol 29, I don't get support for `--iconv` and any filenames with funny characters get screwed up.

```
wim@desk35:~$ rsync -nv --iconv=UTF-8,UTF8-MAC /media/wim/wim_2tb/guitar wim@wim-imac:/Volumes/wim2TB/guitar
rsync: on remote machine: --iconv=UTF8-MAC: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-45/rsync/main.c(1333) [server=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

I looked for any kind of `rsyncd` to kick that might be running on the Mac using `ps aux`, `ps -ef`, but I couldn't find it.

**Why does the mac machine select the old protocol version when contacted from remote, and how can I make it use the newer version of rsync that I've installed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that the homebrewed version of rsync is in /usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin (which is as it should be), but when rsyncing from your linux box it's executing /usr/bin/rsync as the remote agent. If that's the problem, you should be able to fix it by adding `--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync` (or whatever the actual path is on the OS X side).

Note: please don't replace the Apple-supplied version of rsync in the /usr/bin directory -- that way lies madness.

Comment: If you don't have control over the issued command and thus can't add parameters, here's my solution involving a custom login shell script: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392489/77613